# string manipulation : insert words at certain indexes in string, simultaneously

Tags: java, string, replace

I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything that will allow me to insert words at certain indexes simultaneously. For example :
I have a string :

> rock climbing is fun, I love rock climbing.

I have a hashmap for certain words which indicate their index in the string :
e.g. :

```
rock -> 0,29
climbing -> 5,34
fun -> 17
```

Now my question is :
I want to put [start] tag at the start of all these words and [end] tag at the end of them, in the string. I can't do this one by one since in that case once I insert [start] at index 0, then all the other indexes will be modified and I'll have to recalculate them.
Is there a way in which I can insert all of the tags at once or something? Can somebody suggest some other solution to this problem?

I can't use regular expressions(replaceall method), since sometimes I'll have a sentence like :

> rocks are hard.

and hashmap will be :

```
rock -> 0
```

I am looking for faster solutions here.

edit :
for the sentence :

```
rocks are hard but frocks are beautiful.
rocks -> 0
```

Here I don't want to replace frocks with the tags.

Comment: Insert from the latest indices first, then do 1 index recalculation for all your map stuff at the end.  OR, construct a new string, insert tags as you go and record important indices.

Comment: Why is it that you can't use regular expressions replaceall?  What would your expected output of rocks are hard end up as?

Comment: Why are you saving the indices anyway? Can't you insert the tags in the step where you locate the words?

Comment: @NolanPower : I can use regular expression for the given examples, but I can't use them for something like : frocks are beautiful. I don't want to replace rock in this sentence. And basically I want to check and see if these indices are of any use

Comment: @Keppil : I am locating words and their indices, whenever the sentence is received. That time I don't know the hashmap. The hashmap is formed later from the query that is received.

Answer (score -1):

This is not exactly doing what you want, but consider this as an alternative solution what tries to achieve your goal via different means.

I will suppose two different things, firstly, suppose there exists a `List<String> words`, which contains the words you want to replace.

Then code will be:

```
public String insertTags(final String input) {
    for (String word : words) {
        input.replace(word, "[start]" + word + "[end]");
    }
    return input;
}
```

Second case, closer to your example but not using the indices, suppose there exists a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`, which contains the words and the indices to replaces them at in a list representation.

Then code would be:

```
public String insertTags(final String input) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : words.entrySet()) {
        String word = entry.getKey();
        input.replace(word, "[start]" + word + "[end]");
    }
    return input;
}
```

The latter is definately more complex and does not even use the indices, so preferably you should rewrite it to the former.

Hope this helps you without having to worry about the indices.

Comment: This is again the use of regular expression via replace function. I'll have to write a complex one if I really decide to use that.
e.g. : take my latest edit. In that case your code will replace rock from frocks as well.

Comment: @tejas Ah then I am sorry for that, but you hadn't mentioned that yet at first. It can still be done however via regular expressions: You can for example only replace something if a blank predeces it, or if a blank comes after it, etc. etc. However for an optimal answer you will need to know all cases that can occur and how you want to deal with them.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know all the cases that will occur. Thats the problem. Thats why I am trying to solve this through indices.